# php - Can't insert array into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
if ($response_array[0] == 1) {
    $table = payments_received;
    function mysql_insert_array($table, $response_array) {
    foreach ($response_array as $field=>$value) {
        $fields[] = '`' . $field . '`';
        $values[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }
    $field_list = implode(',', $fields);
    $value_list = implode(', ', $values);

    $query = "INSERT INTO `" . $table . "` (" . $field_list . ") VALUES (" . $value_list . ")";
        if (!$query) { 
        $message = mysql_error();
        die($message);
    }
    }

    include('receipt.php');
}
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work? I know the condition at the top is satisfied because the script goes on to include receipt.php (bottom of code). I know that $response_array has data because of this as well (plus I use the data from it in the receipt). I get no error output at all despite the condition under $query (by the way, my MySQL connection info is specified at the top of the script by including config.inc.php which is in perfect working order). I hope I'm not missing something glaringly obvious.

---

UPDATE #1:

As several of you pointed out I didn't actually call mysql_query(as I feared I was missing some glaringly obvious stuff that goes to show that my brain is not functioning on a high level). I took Gus' edits and tried them, fixing the unbalanced braces and adding mysql_query() (as Frank mentioned). Here's what I have:

```
function mysql_insert_array($table, $response_array) {
    foreach ($response_array as $field=>$value) {
    $fields[] = '' . $field . '';
    $values[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }
    $field_list = implode(',', $fields);
    $value_list = implode(', ', $values);
```

```
$field_list = rtrim($fieldlist,",");
$value_list = rtrim($value_list,",");

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `" . $table . "` (" . $field_list . ") VALUES (" . $value_list . ")");
if (!$query) { 
$message = mysql_error();
die($message);
}
```

}

if ($response_array[0] == 1) {
    $table = "payments_received";
    mysql_insert_array($table, $response_array);
    include('receipt.php');
} else {
    include('declined.php');
}

I get further and at least get an error code, which is...

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,' at line 1

...I know that the problem is the trailing comma but I keep running into this problem today and have yet to figure out how to get rid of that damn extra comma in a situation like this. Ideas?

Thank you all for your help so far.

---

UPDATE #2

Answered my own question. I used rtrim($field_list,",") and rtrim($value_list,",") with a successful result. See updates to the code in UPDATE #1.... Or not! I just realized when I was pasting the code above that I had typoed and forgot the underscore in field_list in one place... I added it back and tested again and it didn't work. Same error as the one above. However when the typo remains in place the code works and does exactly what I want. WTF!?

---

FINAL UPDATE

I did what I wanted with the code below. I added ` around $field on line 3 of the code below (I don't know what that character is called).

```
function mysql_insert_array($table, $response_array) {
    foreach ($response_array as $field=>$value) {
    $fields[] = "$field";
    $values[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }
    $field_list = implode(',', $fields);
    $value_list = implode(', ', $values);
```

```
$field_list = rtrim($field_list,",");
echo "$field_list <br />";
$value_list = rtrim($value_list,",");
echo "$value_list <br />";

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `" . $table . "` ($field_list) VALUES (" . $value_list . ")");
if (!$query) { 
$message = mysql_error();
die($message);
}
```

}

if ($response_array[0] == 1) {
    $table = "payments_received";
    mysql_insert_array($table, $response_array);
    include('receipt.php');
} else {
    include('declined.php');
}

Comment: I've updated my reply.  Have a look.

Comment: @Kerin Thanks. I made another update to my question as well.

Comment: without seeing the rest of your code I'd have to hazard the guess that the rtrim function where you dropped the underscore behaves unpredictably when fed undefined values.  That's not a real guess and I'm not happy with it, but I'll have another look in the morning.  Additionally, I note that in your implode() functions you're using ',' as delimiter in the first implode, and ', ' as delimiter for the second.  And thirdly, I'd like to add that the whole rtrim thing is weird and unnecessary, just do implode() with '' as your delimiter and you'll get instant concatenated strings!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't actually executed $query, like with mysql_query($query);

:)

Ryan's probably right too, but this is specifically why your query isn't working - as far as PHP is concerned, you've built the query and then not bothered to do anything productive with it.

---

Edit 1: Frank?! Man, way to show the love.  :)

But I jest.  You can do a couple of things; either use substr() to clip the trailing comma off the end and then append a ; in its place with normal string concatenation, or alternatively switch your do while loop for a for () loop and add an if-clause that selectively drops a "," or a ";" in based on whether your counter is equal to the size of the source array minus one.

I'd do the substr one, personally.

Comment: Oh, RYAN is right, but no one else who mentioned it is, eh?  ;)  You and you're "you have to actually execute the query" - ugh.  Maybe he didn't WANT to execute the query - maybe it was his intention to just write a pretty query so we could admire it.

Comment: Nobody else had mentioned it when I said that!  I mean, that I saw.  Either that or I'm a hateful jerk.  Ask my wife.

Comment: @Dave i got you by 21 seconds, fair and square!

Comment: I CANT TAKE ALL THIS FIGHTING MOMMY DADDY PLEASE STOP IT

Comment: @Ryan - 21 seconds and 1 down-vote later, and I'm off the island. :)

Comment: @dave, it's okay.  it's going to be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

`$table = payments_received;`

PHP is looking for a literal named `payments_received`; you probably meant:

`$table = "payments_received";`

Comment: This only causes a PHP notice on my machine — the language assumes by `payments_received` that the intended value is `"payments_received"`.

Comment: also, as pointed out by Kerin, he isn't actually executing a query! each problem, by itself, is enough to prevent data from actually being inserted

Comment: @Hans very curious! thanks for pointing that out. well, as long as he's not using spaces in his literal i guess he's ok :)

Comment: Still, it's a language "feature" of PHP one should probably not rely on :)

Comment: the most surprising part is that the error is only notice-level

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is

```
$table = payments_received;
```

should be

```
$table = "payments_received";
```

The next improvement can be:

```
"INSERT INTO `" . $table . "` ("
```

should be

```
"INSERT INTO `$table` ("
```

leading to the point where you need to execute

```
$result = mysql_query($query)
```

Comment: that second point is a non-issue, because they would evaluate to the same thing. the real problem, as Kerin pointed out, is that he's not actually executing the query

Comment: Your "next problem" isn't a problem.  What's wrong w/ the way he wrote it?  I actually like his way better, since he's not putting a variable in a string.

Comment: @Ryan Updated as you were typing.

Answer (score 0):

You made two main mistakes: you forgot to add "" on that 2nd line is the small one, and the main one is that you never actually execute the function. You have to define the function first, then you can execute it in your `if()` statement.

Hopefully this works for you:

```
function mysql_insert_array($table, $response_array) {
    foreach ($response_array as $field=>$value) {
    $fields[] = '' . $field . '';
    $values[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }
    $field_list = implode(',', $fields);
    $value_list = implode(', ', $values);


    $query = "INSERT INTO `" . $table . "` (" . $field_list . ") VALUES (" . $value_list . ")";
    if (!$query) { 
    $message = mysql_error();
    die($message);
}

if ($response_array[0] == 1) {
    $table = "payments_received";
    mysql_insert_array($table, $response_array);
}

include('receipt.php');
```

Comment: you also forgot that he doesn't ever execute the query :x

Comment: You're right that he declares mysql_insert_array() and never calls it (which the other answers to date have missed), but you forgot to call mysql_query, and you have unbalanced curly braces, so your code is a few tweaks away from working as well.

Comment: Thanks Gus, Ryan, and Frank. I made some amendments but am still having issues. See Update #1 in the question.